# Facebook Graph API - IG Media Getting Metadata Issue

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have some issues about IGMedia getting metadatas. I followed the instructions in documentations. But I am getting an error like "400" "Bad Request". Before try to getting IGMedia metadatas , I took the recent media datas. But ı dont get an error. Its worked perfectly. So ı need to help about why ı am getting that error? Because of permissions or another things? Please help me. Here is the code. And ı get the error, line of // Get IGMedia Metadata

```
        string access_token = "ACCESS_TOKEN";
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
      {
         { "access_token", access_token},
         { "scope","instagram_basic,manage_pages"},
         { "redirect_uri","" },
      };


        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var response = new HttpClient().PostAsync("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/device/login", content);
        response.Wait();
        if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new Exception("Auth failed");
        var responseString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        responseString.Wait();

        dynamic data = Json.Decode(responseString.Result);

        Console.WriteLine("Code : " + data.code);
        Console.WriteLine("User Code : " + data.user_code);
        Console.WriteLine("Verification Uri : " + data.verification_uri);
        Console.WriteLine("Expires in : " + data.expires_in + " seconds");
        Console.WriteLine("Interval : " + data.interval);

        int interval = Convert.ToInt32(data.interval) * 1000;
        int expires_in = Convert.ToInt32(data.expires_in);
        string longCode = data.code;

        bool loggedIn = false;
        DateTime dtCodeGenerated = DateTime.Now;

        string TokenCall = "";
        int TokenExpireTime;

        while (!loggedIn)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(interval);

            // Poll Login Status
            values = new Dictionary<string, string>
      {
         { "access_token", access_token },
         { "code",longCode}
      };


            content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            response = new HttpClient().PostAsync("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/device/login_status", content);
            response.Wait();
            if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                throw new Exception("Login Status failed");
            responseString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            responseString.Wait();

            data = Json.Decode(responseString.Result);


            if (data.access_token != null)
            {
                loggedIn = true;

                TokenCall = data.access_token;
                TokenExpireTime = Convert.ToInt32(data.expires_in);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (data.error != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(data.error.error_user_title);
                }

            }


            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Expires in : {0:000} seconds", (expires_in - (DateTime.Now - dtCodeGenerated).TotalSeconds)));


        }
        // Get Profile
        response = new HttpClient().GetAsync("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?fields=name,picture&access_token=" + TokenCall);
        response.Wait();
        if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new Exception("Profile Get failed");
        responseString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        responseString.Wait();

        data = Json.Decode(responseString.Result);

        Console.WriteLine("Name : " + data.name);
        Console.WriteLine("User picture : " + data.picture.data.url);
        Console.WriteLine("Id : " + data.id);

        string userID = data.id;




        // Get User's Pages

        response = new HttpClient().GetAsync("https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/me/accounts?access_token=" + TokenCall);
        response.Wait();
        if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new Exception("Profile Get failed");
        responseString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        responseString.Wait();

        data = Json.Decode(responseString.Result);


        string selectedBusinessAccountID = "";
        if (data.data.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.data.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PAGE " + i.ToString());

                Console.WriteLine("Name : " + data.data[i].name);
                Console.WriteLine("Category : " + data.data[i].category);
                Console.WriteLine("Id : " + data.data[i].id);

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();

                string pageID = data.data[i].id;

                // get Instagram Business Account
                response = new HttpClient().GetAsync(String.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/{0}?fields=instagram_business_account&access_token={1}", pageID, TokenCall));
                response.Wait();
                if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    throw new Exception("Profile Get failed");
                responseString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                responseString.Wait();

                dynamic data_instagram_business = Json.Decode(responseString.Result);

                if (data_instagram_business.instagram_business_account != null)
                {
                    selectedBusinessAccountID = data_instagram_business.instagram_business_account.id;
                    Console.WriteLine("selectedBusinessAccountID : " + selectedBusinessAccountID);

                    break;
                }
            }

            // Get Hashtag id
            response = new HttpClient().GetAsync(String.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/ig_hashtag_search?user_id={0}&q={2}&access_token={1}", selectedBusinessAccountID, TokenCall, "hisseliharikalar"));
            response.Wait();
            if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                throw new Exception("Hashtag ID Failed");
            responseString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            responseString.Wait();

            data = Json.Decode(responseString.Result);
            string hashtagID = "";
            if (data.data.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < data.data.Length; i++)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Id : " + data.data[i].id);
                    hashtagID = data.data[i].id;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    break;
                }

            }




            // Get Medias of hashtag

            response = new HttpClient().GetAsync(String.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/recent_media?user_id={1}&fields={3}&access_token={2}", hashtagID, selectedBusinessAccountID, TokenCall, "id,media_type,comments_count,like_count,media_url,caption,children"));
            response.Wait();
            if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                throw new Exception("Hashtag Medias Failed");
            responseString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            responseString.Wait();

            data = Json.Decode(responseString.Result);

            if (data.data.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < data.data.Length; i++)
                {




                    Console.WriteLine("Id : " + data.data[i].id);
                    Console.WriteLine("like_count : " + data.data[i].like_count);
                    Console.WriteLine("caption : " + data.data[i].caption);
                    Console.WriteLine("media_type : " + data.data[i].media_type);
                    Console.WriteLine("media_url : " + data.data[i].media_url);
                    if (data.data[i].media_url == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("children  : " + data.data[i].children);

                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();


                    **// Get IGMedia Metadata**

                    response = new HttpClient().GetAsync(String.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}?fields={3}&access_token={2}", data.data[i].id, selectedBusinessAccountID, TokenCall, "id,like_count,caption,media_type,media_url,comments_count"));
                    response.Wait();
                    if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        throw new Exception("IGMedia metadata Failed");
                    responseString = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    responseString.Wait();

                    data = Json.Decode(responseString.Result);

                        Console.WriteLine("Id : " + data.data[i].id);
                        Console.WriteLine("like_count : " + data.data[i].like_count);
                        Console.WriteLine("caption : " + data.data[i].caption);
                        Console.WriteLine("media_type : " + data.data[i].media_type);
                        Console.WriteLine("media_url : " + data.data[i].media_url);
                        Console.WriteLine("comment_count : " + data.data[i].comments_count);

                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine();


                }

            }


            // 
        }





        //End
        Console.ReadKey();



    }


}
```

}

Comment: If that access_token above contains your actual app id and secret, then the first thing you should do now is go and reset your app secret via your app dashboard.

Comment: _“I followed the instructions in documentations.”_ - which ones? _Link_ to them,. instead of being so vague. Right now, from the endpoint URL used there, it looks like you are trying to implement [Login for Devices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices) - what is that supposed to have to do with getting IG media meta data in the first place? You should probably be following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started here.

Comment: @04FS it was just an example showing that there was no problem in the application. here is the documentation which i am used https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media#metadata

Comment: You are making over half a dozen API requests in the code you have shown us - so which one are you even talking about?

Comment: @04FS You're right. Getting IGMedia Metadata error is below that comment line. Its beginning with ** for attract your attention.

Comment: Have you checked what the URL string you are assembling there actually looked like then?

Comment: The response _body_ might contain a more detailed error description.

Comment: @04FS when ı open the URL with values ı getting this error "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '17866783921607034' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api".

Comment: @04FS Here is the link you can try "https://graph.facebook.com/17866783921607034?fields=id,like_count,caption,media_type,media_url,comments_count&access_token=EAAEF0hlIiMABAOsdYdizHOTxYykxPa22xEQEUHshZAOkDhtjiDbrcoAutIwClMkmObWFXGItcImgwvSVgk3vySDuZCxIZCZCZBvtprD1N1SeUIhYJAMoOYHQwzt19N5ZC8AYlp47ZAYZAy7ZCqjhj9ZBfyuZAGUOZB5b7OAZD"

Comment: Well most likely you don’t actually have the necessary permission then, to request any details about the object in question.

Comment: **Stop publishing valid access tokens!** You are currently giving everyone here who reads this access to the list of pages your user manages, and that way even page access tokens for those pages.

Comment: @04FS this is a little example for my project. Because of that ı didn't care to see the token appear. But thanks for your suggestion :) By the way the error still continues.. Can you help me ?

Comment: @04FS hey body , please contact me with mail. I am really in trouble. You can help me. Please contact with selim@hisseliharikalar.com please...